# Pandas plotting with multiple index labels

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame that looks something like this:

```
n=pd.DataFrame({1:[1,2,np.NAN,4],2:[5,6,5,8],'info':[5,6,8,7],'moreinfo':[1,2,5,8]}).set_index(['info','moreinfo'])
```

Which looks like this:

```
                       1    2
info    moreinfo        
5       1            1.0    5
6       2            2.0    6
8       5            NaN    5
7       8            4.0    8
```

How can I line plot this such that:

The column labels are used as the  xlabels
The data is grouped and colored by index
The y-axis is the numerical data found within each column.

Below is an example of what I'm thinking the plot should look like:

[image]

Comment: Can you show me what your graph should look like.  What does "The data is grouped and colored by index" two indexes, info and more info.

Comment: What did you try so far? Could you draw a small sketch of the desired output? How should `NaN` be treated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try:

```
ax = n.T.plot(marker='o')
ax.set_xticks(n.T.index.astype(int))
```

Output:

[image]

You might want to fill that NaN with zero.

```
ax = n.fillna(0).T.plot(marker='o')
ax.set_xticks(n.T.index.astype(int))
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: I just thought to try this, and it worked nicely. I assume there must be some way to specify the x labels versus the data labels other than transforming the DataFrame. But in any case, this does work nicely. Thanks.